# Is there a way to construct a constexpr function to get bit representation of a double?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

Is there a standard way to construct a constexpr function that allows conversion of double to it's 64 bit representation:

```
constexpr uint64_t double_to_uint64_t(double d) {
   ??????
}
```

So that

```
constexpr uint64_t two_bits = double_to_uint64_t(2.0);
```

would compile?

The reverse method (uint64 to double) is also of interest.

Comment: I am only interested in the platforms where double is IEEE-754 64 bit floating point type.

Comment: Which representation?  Thr same value?  The compiler hardware?  The target platform hardware?

Comment: What do you mean by "its 64 bit representation", exactly?

Comment: I woud like to get a result equivalent to memcpy(&bits, &d, sizeof(double)), where bits is uint64_t, and d is a double.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not until C++20. All of the usual tricks are either outright forbidden (`reinterpret_cast`) or undefined behavior, and UB becomes ill-formed when executed at compile-time.

C++20 provides `std::bit_cast`, which does binary conversion between two types, so long as they are both trivially copyable and have the same size. And the function is `constexpr`, so you can use it at compile-time.

Comment: Reading a double bytewise via a pointer to char is not UB, neither is copying it to an unsigned int.  Doing that constexpr, however...

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont: One big issue is that constexpr is evaluated on the compiler host. Which may be different than the compiler target.